# What is difference between datetime and timestamp

Tags: sql-server-2005

What is difference between datetime and timestamp datatype in Sql Server?.

Comment: The duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105093/difference-between-datetime-and-timestamp-in-sqlserver has discussions, that may be interesting to read

Answer (score 47, accepted):

One is a date and time, the other is a column type that is updated every time a row is updated.

[Note timestamp is being deprecated; use [rowversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=SQL.90).aspx) instead]

Answer (score 9):

Timestamp (deprecated synonym for rowversion) :

> Is a data type that exposes automatically generated, unique binary numbers within a database. rowversion is generally used as a mechanism for version-stamping table rows. The storage size is 8 bytes. The rowversion data type is just an incrementing number and does not preserve a date or a time. To record a date or time, use a datetime2 data type.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Normally time-stamp used when ever you inserted new record into database automatically system would take default date time
   ex : transaction like bank deposit or with draw

data-time datatype used at the movement of inserting the user defined date into the record 
    ex : date of birth

Answer (score -2):

**timestamp** is the synonym for the **rowversion** data type and is subject to the behavior of data type synonyms. In DDL statements, use **rowversion** instead of **timestamp** wherever possible. In simple way to tell, It means the updating time of row. **datetime** means the  time of creation of row.
DateTime is constant and other is changeable as the real time and local time.

Comment: In some versions of SQL Server, rowversion is the synonym e.g. SQL Server 2005. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms182776(v=sql.90)