# Different between datetime2 and timestamp in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I used "timestamp" in build table in sql server 2008, but i want know ,if i used "datatime2" in build table, that is same "timestamp".
if same why but two type in sql server 2008.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460197/what-is-difference-between-datetime-and-timestamp

Comment: As well as asking here, you may want to consider reading the documentation, which explains in detail what the [`datetime2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335(v=sql.100).aspx) and [`timestamp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=sql.100).aspx) data types are.

Comment: "What is difference between datetime and timestamp" link not work

Answer (score 0):

Well, DateTime2 is a type, and Timestamp is another. The data stored by those 2 types is clearly different. You may want to have a look at documentation about those 2 types to understand the difference...

Answer (score 0):

`timestamp` is a deprecated synonym for [`RowVersion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).  It has nothing to do with dates or times or `DateTime2`.