# Is there a way to store timestamp in access?

Tags: ms-access, timestamp, ms-access-2013

I want to create a table with timestamp field in Microsoft Access 2013, but there are not timestamp or rowverion datatype. How do I do this?
Is there a way to store timestamp in access?

Comment: Exactly, what are you trying to accomplish? You mention rowversion. In SQL Server, rowversion and timestamp are synonyms. They are exactly the same thing and have nothing to do with date/time. They are binary data automatically updated whenever the record is changed. So, are you looking for something like that? Or simply the Date/Time that the record was updated?

Comment: Yes, I want something exactly like the rowverion in SQL. I can use a date/time field and update manually after change data to Now(). But i want a column that automatically updated after data changing.

Comment: Ahmad. Your answer contradicts itself. You say you want exactly like SQL Server rowversion. Timestamp is just another name for rowversion. Both have NOTHING to do with date/time. Yet you also say that you could do it with Now() - you can't because rowversion is binary data NOT date/time. So, I ask again. Which do you want?

Comment: I want a column That Show Is data has changed or not, And if they has changed, How many times? 
Sorry if my English is not so good!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is same as TIMESTAMP datatype in Access?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265685/what-is-same-as-timestamp-datatype-in-access)

Comment: The answer is No, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265685/what-is-same-as-timestamp-datatype-in-access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your last comment, you need two fields:
LastEdited (Date/Time with default = Now()) and TimesEdited (long integer with default = 0).
LastEdited = Now()
TimesEdited = TimesEdited + 1
Since you are using Access 2013, you can set a data macro to update both whenever the record is edited.

Comment: This is OK, but not completely automatic ;-)

Comment: @Ahmad - It would be completely automatic if you used an event-driven [Data Macro](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Create-a-data-macro-b1b94bca-4f17-47ad-a66d-f296ef834200?CorrelationId=3d9c89a1-301e-4d1b-9c80-d6ca7a6de10a&ui=en-US&rs=en-CA&ad=CA) like the answer suggests.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, though only with a resolution of one second - set the field `=Now()`.

For a resolution of about 1/18 second, add the fractional part of `Timer`:

```
Timestamp = Now() + (Timer() - Int(Timer())) / 86400)
```