# How to manage an ImportHistory in a Database?

Tags: sql-server, database, history

I have a table ImportHistory in which I store history of importation. (Each time the user upload a file I store a row).

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ImportHistory]
(
    [Id]   INT  IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Date] TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ImportHistory] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)
```

And I have also

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sales] (
    [Id]              VARCHAR (150)   NOT NULL,
  ...
    [ImportHistoryId] INT             NOT NULL,
  ...
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Sales_ImportHistory] FOREIGN KEY ([ImportHistoryId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ImportHistory] ([Id])
);
```

The question is how to properly take the ID of ImportHistory and store it each time I insert a line in SALES for this import session ?

Comment: I believe for every sale insert,you have 2 make to inserts, 1 in ImportHistiry and 1 in Sales. Once you insert in ImportHistory you acquire the id and use as ImportHistoryId in sales insert

Answer (score 1):

1. You insert a row in `ImportHistory`.
2. You [`SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1920558/87698) to get the ID of the newly created record.
3. You insert your Sales records, using the value acquired in Step 2 as the `ImportHistoryID`.

PS: The [timestamp data type is not what you think it is.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4460197/87698) You probably want to use [date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) or [datetime2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) instead.