# Execute SQL-Query stored in column while selecting

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

- Table `A` contains the columns `ID` and `Query`.
- Table `B` contains the columns `ID`, `Value` and `Category`.

In every row of table `A` (without any exceptions) the column `Query` contains an SQL query as nvarchar, which looks something like `SELECT * FROM B WHERE Category = 1`.

I cannot figure out, how i can execute all Queries of table `A` and merge those results and return them (inside a select statement).

I already tried to iterate through all rows in table `A`, inserting the results of `EXEC(Query)` into a temporary table `#C` and finally execute `SELECT * FROM #C`. But i was not successful with this solution.

---

**EDIT**

Just for clarification: The columns and their data types of the resultsets of the queries - stored in table `A` -  are identical. Table `B` just has a column with datatype [`[timestamp]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=sql.90).aspx). The exception i receive is:

> Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column. Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the timestamp column, or insert a DEFAULT into the timestamp column

Comment: You've provided a link to vintage documentation for `timestamp`. Have you read it? The value is supplied by the database and provides a `rowversion` for each row, not a date/time. ([This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460197/what-is-difference-between-datetime-and-timestamp) SO question addresses the differences between `timestamp` and `datetime`.)

Comment: It sounds like you just want to do a dynamic sql statement where you concatenate all the Select statements from table A with a UNION ALL in between each Select statement.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

You can run all the queries using a T-SQL statement.  That is, a `WHILE` loop with a cursor or similar mechanism to run each query using dynamic SQL.

Putting the results into a single table is problematic.  All the queries would need to return the same columns in the same order with the same types.  It doesn't look to me like `SELECT * FROM B` and `SELECT * FROM #C` would meet these conditions.

You probably need to think more about what you really need to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should get you what you want if I understand the question.

```
DECLARE @sqlStatement NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @sqlStatement += CONCAT(Query,' UNION ALL ')
FROM TableA
;

SET @sqlStatement = LEFT(@sqlStatement, LEN(@sqlStatement) - 10 );

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlStatement;
```