# Timestamp data type not working in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL, I created a table 'Meetings' with meeting_start, and meeting_end features with the datatype 'timestamp'. When I try to insert values in the table, I get an error or I get a window that pops up 'Enter Binds' and I'm not sure why or what to do when it pops up. Here is the INSERT code:

```
insert into Meeting values (1, 2016-12-25 10:00:00, 2016-12-25 12:00:00);
```

This is the pop up window:
[image]
Any help on how to get the code to work is appreciated.

Comment: You can change to datetime type  like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/75de0/1 for timestamp.

Comment: @PrabhathAmaradasa good point regarding the quotes

Comment: Can you please post your table declaration? You say that you have 2 cols defined as timestamp, but afaik you can only declare one.

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` in SQL Server has *absolutely nothing* to do with date & time - it's a system-internal, binary counter, really. If you want to store date and time, use `DATETIME2(n)` (for SQL Server 2008 and newer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Meeting  VALUES( 1,'2016-12-25 10:00:00', '2016-12-25 12:00:00')
```

Answer (score 2):

Timestamp is not compatible with datetime values, see the documentation here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx
and this SO question [What is difference between datetime and timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460197/what-is-difference-between-datetime-and-timestamp)

So you cannot insert a string value that is formatted as a datetime value. I suggest that you change your table declaration so that the columns are datetime (or datetime2 depending on your needs)